# Site page title on Categories pages and Product Page

Tags: spartacus-storefront

I'm working with SAP Spartacus lib, version 3.6 and I need to implement a custom page title to Category Page and Product Page.

Actually, on Category Page the title is blank and on Pdp is returning PRODUCT NAME - Website name (I believe it is the default behavior).

I have looked back on Backoffice and my category already has a Description and I need to format my Product Page title to remove the Product name.

On SAP Spartacus Docs I've found this documentation, but for me do not explain how to implement this object on module.

```
{
 provide: PageMetaResolver,
 useExisting: YourCustomPageMetaResolver,
 multi: true,
}
```

https://sap.github.io/spartacus-docs/html-tags/#customizing-meta-tags

Anyone can help me?
Thanks for your time.